# In TensorFlow keras, how do I load the weights of another model while skipping incompatible layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use `load_weights` function from `tf.keras.Model` but it does not seem to work properly.

If I call `model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True, skip_mismatch=True)` I get an error for mismatch for shape, which is precisely what I expected the `"skip_mismatch"` argument to take care of.

This code snippet is a relatively simple `mnist` dataset case that reproduces my error. I run this in google colab and the thing that happens is just like in my own code.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

#import mnist dataset in x,y fashion
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

#build a simple model with sequential dense layers
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

#compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])
#create checkpoint directory
os.makedirs("checkpoints", exist_ok=True)
cp_callback =  tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("checkpoints/cp-{epoch:04d}.ckpt",
                save_weights_only=True,
            )

#train the model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[cp_callback])

model2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
])
#compile model2
model2.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])


#load weights of model into model2
model2.load_weights("checkpoints/cp-0010.ckpt",by_name=True, skip_mismatch=True)
```

I get

> "Received incompatible tensor with shape (10,) when attempting to restore variable with shape (5,) and name dense_5/bias:0." whether I use `skip_mismatch=True` or `skip_mismatch=False`.

Am I using the function wrong? What is the proper way to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the docs of [load_weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights) and [save_weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save_weights), it should get clearer.
From `load_weights`:

> **Weight loading by name**
>
> *If your weights are saved as a .h5 file created via model.save_weights(), you can use the argument by_name=True.*
>
> In this case, weights are loaded into layers only if they share the same name. This is useful for fine-tuning or transfer-learning models where some of the layers have changed.

And from `save_weights`:

> **save_format**    Either 'tf' or 'h5'. *A filepath ending in '.h5' or '.keras' will default to HDF5* if save_format is None. Otherwise, None becomes 'tf'. Defaults to None.

From `ModelCheckpoint`:

> **save_weights_only**     if True, then only the model's weights will be saved (model.save_weights(filepath)), else the full model is saved (model.save(filepath)).

Seems like you don't save in the .h5 format, and therefore can not use `by_name=True`. ModelCheckpoint just calls `model.save_weights(path)` without `save_format`, and your savepath ending is neither `.keras` nor `.h5`.

Note: For now I can't test this solution, and it is just citing the docs. I'll come back later and test this, if necessary.